# How to do " If Modified Since "

Tags: .htaccess, caching, last-modified

I verify my website with a SEO tools, and between the errors that I get the `" If Modified Since "`

When I learn about it I found that about caching, and if you modify something you drop the cache

about caching I have this `.htaccess` code

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
```

But I want to add the `If Modified Since` any solution ?

(I try to search about it but without any results)